# How to autorefresh my Ajax inside of a condition

Tags: javascript

**using the following approach throw me an error stating unknock resource,so where should put the setInterval ?**

```
   $("#faultstat").click(function(e) {
      var dtFrom = $("#datepickerFrom").val();
      var dtTo = $("#datepickerTo").val();
      tmp = $("#multiselect").val();

     setInterval(

         $.ajax({

             dataType: "json",
             type: "POST",
             url: "@Url.Action("SumAndAverage","Ranking")",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             data: JSON.stringify({ "regionalManager": tmpString, "dtFrom": dtFrom, "dtTo": dtTo }),
             success: function (result) {

                 var average = result.sumOfProAndAvg[0].avg;
                 var sumOfpro = result.sumOfProAndAvg[0].sum;
                 var failed = result.fld.Text;
                 var disabled = result.dsld.Text;
                 var powerConv = result.pwr.Text;

             }
         }), 30000);

 });
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate **autorefresh it every 10 minutes**

Comment: @nikhilagw which function should i call?

Comment: Do you want to click on the button and then send ajax call every 10 minutes? If yes, then do you want to disable the click after that?

Comment: @nikhilagw no I don't want to disable the click that's the manual option of refreshing and filtering,but I want this part (ajax) to be refresh every 10minutes after the button clicked(first time),I want this autorefresh take of my data if the use didn't click on filter after 10 mints

Comment: Once you click you want to send the ajax and then send the ajax every 10 minutes. Is my understanding correct? Also, what will happen if you click the button more than one time?

Comment: @nikhilagw correct,button and this auto refresh does the same action,the only difference is,in the autorefresh  user does not need to press the button anymore

Comment: Try using `setInterval`

Comment: @nikhilagw I need to pass(functionName,Time) but in my case what I should put here in functionName

Comment: time you know i.e. 10 minutes (in milliseconds). the function being an anonymous function and put your ajax inside it. Or create a function for your ajax and refer the function name there

Comment: @nikhilagw the setinterval should be inside my click event or outside?

Comment: It will be inside your click event

Comment: @nikhilagw updated my question,it gives me an error

Comment: Refer here - http://plnkr.co/edit/ycuAH33gGVZRxQSu15mR?p=catalogue